# Linux/Unix Executables && FSH with libs/executing sequence

Tags: debian, executable, binary

Okay, relatively new Linux User here. (Messed around with Linux for ages, looking for more depth)

I know that all files in Linux can be executed if they have the executable bit.

What are these files?
For example, in `/usr/bin` there is a `xyzexample` file. Is this file pure binary, or is it a middle language such as assembler or C?

Now that file links to a lib in `/usr/lib` how is said linking done? The files in the dir are .o files. This is object files like binary or machine code correct?

Now, I execute `xyzexample`. How does the execution sequence work? How does it link and start the program?

Comment: `xyzexample` could even be a script.

Answer (score 1):

What kind is file you can see by following command

```
file xyzexample
```

*Executable bit* is a different thing. You can see it by

```
ls -l xyzexample
```

or

```
stat xyzexample
```

For simple understanding it the right to execute file by call it just by name

```
xyzexample
```

will execute programm listed in file. Without this *bit* you are still able to execute it but in different way, for example

```
bash xyzexample
```

Please note, that if the programm file there isn't in folders listed in special variable `PATH` you should indicate the full path for the file:

```
bash /usr/bin/xyzexample
```